# aggregator not aggregating splitted messages after amqp confirm

Tags: spring-integration

1. I have a db query that get a list of IDs
2. I split them using splitter into a channel with a task executor
3. Then I publish amqp messages for every Id

Requirement: I need to confirm that all the messages have been published before I proceed to the next step.

So I added an aggregator after message ack channel

ISSUE: for smaller number of IDs (maybe less than 3000 records), the solution is working as expected. But for larger number of IDs, the aggregator is stuck waiting

The number of published messages is always correct. So I added in the code below a db update to have a counter after the confirm channel and the count is less than the number of IDs for larger list of IDs

```
<!-- service activator query database table and return list of IDs of type: Message<List<Map<String, Object>>> -->

<int:splitter id= "accountsSplitter" input-channel="listOfAccountsChannel" output-channel="accountChannel" />   
<int:channel id="accountChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="splitterTaskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<int:chain id="publishMessageChain" input-channel="accountChannel">
    <int:transformer ref="accountIdTransformer"/>

    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter 
        amqp-template="amqpTemplateCore" 
        confirm-ack-channel="messageAckChannel"
        confirm-nack-channel="messageAckChannel"
        return-channel="messageAckChannel"
        confirm-correlation-expression="#root"
        exchange-name="ABC"
        routing-key="#{abcRoutingKey}">
    </int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>
</int:chain>

<int:chain id="confirmMessageChain" input-channel="messageAckChannel" output-channel="successMessageChannel">
    <int:header-enricher id="replyChannelHeaderEnricher">
        <int:reply-channel expression="payload.headers['replyChannel']" />
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int:transformer id="payloadTransformer" expression="payload" />
</int:chain>

<int:aggregator id="messagesConfirmedAggregator" input-channel="successMessageChannel" output-channel="aggregateChannel"/>

  <task:executor id="splitterTaskExecutor" pool-size="10-40" queue-capacity="1000" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />
```

Comment: Do you see your comments here? Can you read them and understand? Please, respect our time and make your questions as readable as possible. Right now you have to move all these bean definitions to your question as an edit and format them properly. Only after that we will have something to think and play pursuing the help for you. Sorry, if I sound rude...

Comment: I apologize having the question not readable, and I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The number of published messages is always correct.

What makes you think so?

Let's add `confirm-nack-channel` to see the "negative publisher confirms"!

And maybe `return-channel` as well to see how "returned messages will be sent" if that.

**UPDATE**

After some local testing I found the root of cause.

You use concurrent thread pool for sending as `40` (max). By default `CachingConnectionFactory` uses `25`. When the cache size is exceeded a new volatile `Channel` is created, which may wait for confirmation just only 5 seconds.

You should increase `CachingConnectionFactory.setChannelCacheSize()` to pretty big value to meet your concurrent and confirmation requirements.

Comment: If the number of confirmed acks is correct, bean id testcount will have the correct count of messages and the aggregator will proceed with the next step as it has the correct number of messages back.

Comment: When I removed task-executor, the aggregator is not stuck anymore! I sent 25,000 IDs, all messages have been published and after around 5 min the aggregator continued the flow

Comment: Right, because `confirm-ack` is done in async manner and only after some reaction from the Broker side. The issue with `task-executor` you can fix via `CallerRunsPolicy` instead of default `AbortPolicy`.

Comment: if you see the above code, I already set it to caller run policy. is there something else i can do as i really need to multi-thread it for performance? This app could receive up to 500,000 IDs

Comment: is there a different suggestion I could try?

Comment: Would you mind simplifying your code to let us play locally? And one more time: where is exactly the problem? Not all messages are confirmed by RabbitMQ or not all of them even send there?

Comment: I simplified code. I added a comment that service activator gets list of account IDs. The messages published is always correct, but the aggregator gets stuck when sending lots of IDs

Comment: Sorry, not clear. You say the same words again and your code is the same. Would you mind at least re-phrase your claim. That does not make so much sense for me. If the aggregator didn't work, we have had a lot of issues already. Anyway I've got your idea and will try to come up with some test-case locally...

Comment: Your ` <int:transformer expression="payload" />` does not make sense. You request `payload` from the `Message` and return it as is. So, it is idempotent and useless.

Comment: Please, look into the UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Hi Artem, it worked by increasing setChannelCacheSize(100), so thanks a lot!